# Odd/even Primitive function

Tags: integration

How do you prove that the primitive function of an odd and continuous function is even without using integrals ? Knowing that both functions,  f and F, are defined on R.

Ps: maybe we can prove that 
F(-x) - F(x) = 0 
But I can't get around proving it tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By differentiation of $F(-x)-F(x)$ wrt. $x$ we get zero since $f$ was odd. Then $F(-x)-F(x)=C$ for any $x$ (this is a constant function). Putting $x=0$ we get $C=0$ and the proof is finished.

Observe that the converse is not true. I have in mind a primitive of an even function. $f(x)=3x^2$ is even, while one of itr primitive is $F(x)=x^3+1$ which is neither odd nor even. Try to check whether or not $G(x)=F(x)-F(0)$ (where $F$ is a prmitive  of an even function $f$) is odd.

Comment: Yes but if we take F(x) = x^3 as the primitive, then it's an odd primitive function of an even function. So basically there always exists an odd primitive function of an even function. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: I do think so - read the 2nd part of my answer.

Comment: I see your point. U're basically saying that u can't prove, using this proof, that the primitive of an even function is odd.

Comment: But I can prove similarly that $G$ defined in my answer is really odd. :) Start with $G(x)+G(-x)$ and follow my argument.

Comment: Using differentiation as well ? I apologize for being a slow learner all of this is new to me bear with me please. Thank you

Comment: Yes, of course, by differentiation. That is why I have written "follow my argument".

Comment: The function u used (G) is obviously odd but how do you prove that generally ? I really tried I don't know how to

Comment: Differentiate $G(x)+G(-x)$ to get $f(x)-f(-x)=0$ for all $x$. Then $G(x)+G(-x)=C$ for some constant $C$. But $G(0)=0$, hence $C=0$. So, $G(x)=-G(-x)$.

Comment: I don't understand why we get 0 by differentiation in both cases. I keep getting 2f(x) or 2f(-x). Is differentiating the same thing as derivating ?

Comment: Yes: to differentiate = to compute a derivative.

Comment: I genuinely thank you for your time. The detail that I was missing is that F'(-x) = -F'(-x) because of the chain rule. I get it now. Thanks again